how to generate a uuid in macos using the CLI
I found this question but it mostly has Linux-related answers.
How to create a UUID in bash?

macOS has a built-in command line tool called uuidgen for generating UUID strings.
$ /usr/bin/uuidgen
195A6362-42A5-4A53-B180-6374841CE233


After a brief search, found this http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/
$ brew install ossp-uuid

$ which uuid
/opt/homebrew/bin/uuid


$ ls -al /opt/homebrew/bin/uuid

/opt/homebrew/bin/uuid -> ../Cellar/ossp-uuid/1.6.2_2/bin/uuid


$ uuid
ed6e5d7c-5501-11ef-b13a-16942bfaf16d


